# adhoc emacs Elisp command to send emacs clipboard text to osx clipboard

Tags: osx, terminal-emacs, yank, clipboard

When you press 'y' (`elfeed-search-yank`) in an *elfeed-search* buffer, the selected entry's permalink url is copied to the *emacs* clipboard.

I don't have any automatic clipboard sync packages installed, and I don't intend to.

**Is it possible to `Meta-:` `Eval:` and tell emacs to send whatever is in the emacs clipboard to the OS (MacOS) clipboard?**

What I tried: browsed the source code for https://github.com/jkp/pbcopy.el/blob/master/pbcopy.el
didn't see any interesting functions

NOTE: I'm using terminal emacs

Comment: I think you just need to set `elfeed-search-clipboard-type` to `'CLIPBOARD`. See also [`(emacs) Clipboard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051871/3084001.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `copy-to-x-clipboard` from `Meta-X` or `Eval:`. No Emacs packages necessary. It relies on the `pbcopy` shell command, which is available in all macOS installations.

```
(defun copy-to-x-clipboard ()
  (interactive) 
  (switch-to-buffer (make-temp-name "scratch"))  
  (insert (current-kill 1))
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "pbcopy")
  (kill-this-buffer))
```

Comment: The question relates to how to fetch some that was already copied to the emacs clipboard. `elfeed-search-yank` and many others copy entries to the emacs clipboard. When that happens, I need a way to upload that from the emacs clipboard to the OS (macOS) clipboard.

Comment: And that's exactly what the above does. It gets the first item from the emacs clipboard, and pushes it to the macOS clipboard.

Comment: I misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to Meta-: Eval: and tell emacs to send whatever is in
>   the emacs clipboard to the OS (MacOS) clipboard?

Yes

```
M-: (call-process-region (car kill-ring) nil "pbcopy")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a GUI Emacs, it should copy automatically everything that goes into kill-ring to the system clipboard. Are you running emacs in a terminal?

To answer your question, the code to copy the latest kill-ring addition to system-kill ring is:

```
(kill-new (current-kill 1))
```

Comment: yes I'm 99% of the time on terminal.app with emacs -nw
.   (kill-new (current-kill 1)) looked promising but didn't work. I'll try again later

Comment: I do not think it will work from within terminal.

Comment: @joshsverns You should update your question with that information. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051871/3084001 for terminal support.